# How to build Snap including multiple directories and files in Snapcraft.yaml

Tags: snap, configuration, ubuntu-core

Is there a example in https://github.com/snapcrafters that would show how to add multiple directories and files as part of the snapcraft build?

I have an entire directory tree that would need to be packaged up.  There is 6 top level directories with subdirectories and files.  I am wanting to create a Snap app out of a binary application.  The main reason for this is because I don't have the source code for a 3rd party application.

I thought I could include the directories by adding them in the "stage:" array, but I am getting errors.

```
parts:
  app1manual:
    # See 'snapcraft plugins'
    plugin: dump
    source: .
    stage: [app1]

apps:
  app1manual:
    command: app1
    plugs:
     - network
     - network-bind
     - system-observe
     - mount-observe
     - network-control
```

How could I add these directories and specify it in the snapcraft.yaml file?